# Errore in cor(PR1, method = "pearson") : supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'

Tags: r, similarity

I'm trying to run:

```
psc = cor(PR1, method = "pearson")
diag(psc) <- 0
```

But I get an error:

> Error in cor(PR1, method = "pearson") : supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'

PR1 is an xlsx file read as a list of numbers.

Comment: Is the structure of `PR1` like you expect? You can have a look at its structure with `str(PR1)`